# local storage is not saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm using firefox beta. I have done a test and my browser says it supports local storage. My code just alerts me the stored variable but every time I close the browser and reopen it the stored number is null, undefined or just blank. I am testing online so it should work. I tested on chrome and it seems to work fine. What possible reasons could there be for it not to work on firefox or other browsers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>  
        <title>local Storage test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="save"> save score</p>
        <p class="alert"> alert score</p>
        <script src="JS/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            localStorage.theScore;
            lastScore="";
            lastScore2="";
            //test if local storage is supported
            if(window.localStorage!==undefined){
                alert('Yes!');
            }else{
                alert('Your browser is outdated!');
            }

            //array to hold score
            var scoreArray={
                score : 500 
            }

            //if user clicks alert 
            $(".alert").click(function(){

                //im trying two ways to here but neither seem to work
                lastScore=localStorage.theScore;    
                lastScore2=localStorage.getItem('theScore');

                alert(lastScore);    
                alert(lastScore2);   
            });

            //when user clicks save it should save variable score in local storage
            $(".save").click(function(){
                localStorage.setItem('theScore', scoreArray.score);

            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"//array to hold score
var scoreArray={"* that's an object. otherwise, does it keep the score when you just reload the page?

Comment: stringfy the objeto to save and parse it to get it from the localStorage is the way

Comment: yes it keeps the score when I reload the page, but not after closing and reopening. Do I have to use JSON to stringfly the object. Would I write it like this:    localStorage.setItem('theScore', JSON.stringfly(scoreArray.score));  ?

Comment: You're only storing the number (as a string - which is fine) so no you don't *need* to serialise the whole object.  There doesn't appear to be anything technically wrong with the code so I'm inclined to suggest that it's something to do with the browser settings - ***i.e.*** if you are clearing the cache you will also likely be clearing the local storage.  (I don't bother with FF but if you are in a developer mode this may be being done automatically).

Comment: could you expand on that, I am trying to understand stringfy.. I realize I spelt it wrong. I will keep trying though thank you

Comment: Ah thank you Emissary! that was my problem. I have unchecked the clear cache in the options and now it works. I didn't nrealize that I was clearing my storage too. It makes sense now . Thanks!